# SAS generate sequence number by group

Tags: sas

I need to create a sequence number by group in SAS and accumulate by group.

I have a dataset with a column that it says if an event occurs o not as well as the time in case of occurrence. I also have initial datetime and end datetime which I don't represent in my example data.

| Event | Time |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 0.3 |
| 1 | 0.4 |
| 1 | 0.4 |
| 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 0.1 |
| 1 | 0.5 |

I need to assign a sequence number for each group where the event happens and create a cumulative.

It should look something like:

| Event | Time | Group | Cumulative |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 0.3 | 1 | 1.1 |
| 1 | 0.4 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 0.4 | 1 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 0.1 | 2 | 0.6 |
| 1 | 0.5 | 2 | 0 |

I was using the retain function with no luck.

Thanks for your suggestions.
Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
data have;
input Event Time;
datalines;
0 0
0 0
1 0.3
1 0.4
1 0.4
0 0
0 0
1 0.1
1 0.5
;

data want(drop = c g);
   c = 0;
   do _N_ = 1 by 1 until (last.event);
      set have;
      by event notsorted;
      c + time;
      if first.event and event then g + 1;
   end;
   
   do _N_ = 1 to _N_;
      set have;
      group = ifn(event, g, 0);
      cumulative = ifn(_N_ = 1, c, 0);
      output;
   end;
run;
```

**Result:**

```
Event  Time  group  cumulative
0      0.0   0      0.0
0      0.0   0      0.0
1      0.3   1      1.1
1      0.4   1      0.0
1      0.4   1      0.0
0      0.0   0      0.0
0      0.0   0      0.0
1      0.1   2      0.6
1      0.5   2      0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this can help you. I am not sure that it can be done in one pass.

Input data:

```
data a;
input event time;
cards;
0 0
0 0
1 0.3
1 0.4
1 0.4
0 0
0 0
1 0.1
1 0.5
;
run;
```

Code:

```
data group (keep=event time group) cum(keep=group_cnt total_time index=(group_cnt));
 retain group_cnt 0 total_time 0;
 set a end=end_ds;
 if ( not event and lag(event) ) then
   output cum;
 if ( event and not lag(event) ) then
   group_cnt+1;
 if ( not event ) then do;
   total_time=0;
   group=0;
 end;
 else do;
   total_time=sum(total_time, time);
   group=group_cnt;
 end;
 output group;
 if ( end_ds and event ) then
   output cum;
run;

data want;
  keep event time group total_time;
  set group;
  group_cnt=group;
  if ( group and not lag (group)) then
    set cum key=group_cnt;
  else total_time=0;
run;
```

Result:

```
0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
1   0.3 1   1.1
1   0.4 1   0
1   0.4 1   0
0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
1   0.1 2   0.6
1   0.5 2   0
```

Comment: Hi @Egor Lipchinskiy, thanks, your solution also work!